# Java - Wifi API

Tags: java, networking, wifi

I am trying to find out if there is a Wifi API for Java. Something that can connect to Wifi networks and scan them (to find devices). I can't seem to find something like that. Any suggestions? Thanks!

P.S.
I know about the WifiManager for Android, but I am not developing for Android, I am developing with JDK 6.

Comment: I'd say "besides JNI" is a no-go. This seems like very much a deeply OS-specific task. E.g. you'd have to use WMI on Windows, [Wireless Tools](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Tools.html) on Loonix, I'm guessing `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport` on OS X, who knows what on other systems.

Comment: I am not using JNI, since I have Ubuntu, and while reading a Stackoverflow answer, I seemed to come across the idea that JNI is only for Windows

Comment: That's patently false. JNI is an integral part of Java, it's the primary FFI mechanism that's needed for Java to actually work. (For instance to implement `native` methods in the JDK that aren't intrinsics.) That said, I think [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) should be more convenient if you need to create your own bindings. (And might in fact already provide a binding to the WMI stuff.)

Comment: Could you show me an example of using JNI to connect to a wifi network or scan a network, etc.?

Comment: No, since I have no clue how WMI actually works, am terrified of using JNI, and believe a full example would actually be out of scope of SO to explain because of the number of moving parts involved. That said, you might be able to avoid using JNI (always a good thing) on Windows as well because there's a command-line tool to do so: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToConnectToAWirelessWIFINetworkFromTheCommandLineInWindows7.aspx. You should be able to run that tool using [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and parse its output.

Answer (score 8):

Wireless networking cards differ greatly depending on manufacturer and even version, and most operating systems do not have a standardized way of interacting with them. Some computers do not even come with wireless cards. The reason it works so well with Android is because Google can guarantee that every phone that has Android installed has a proper wireless networking interface.

tl;dr no, sorry

Comment: You can connect list wifi networks and connect to them with linux commands like iwlist, wpa_supplicant, ifconfig. Therefore, if there was an JNI implementation on top them, the cards detail become irrelevant.

Comment: why can wifi module of python can do it then?

Comment: @nabin what wifi module for python are you referring to?

Answer (score 3):

You can take help of command line tools to get list of available networks using command "netsh wlan show networks mode=Bssid".
Try below java method.

```
public static ArrayList scanWiFi() {
        ArrayList<String> networkList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            // Execute command
            String command = "netsh wlan show networks mode=Bssid";
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            try {
                p.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())
            );
            String line;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String ssidArr[];

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(line);
                if (line.contains("SSID ") && !line.contains("BSSID ")) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    networkList.add(line.split(":")[1]);
                    //System.out.println("data : " + ssidArr[1]);
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(networkList);            
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return networkList;
    }
```