# how access and use PC Direct WiFi in Java?

Tags: java, android, wifi, wifi-direct

I have searched a lot to find an API or a Code for Java to access and use WiFi Direct. But there is nothing about it.

Why all new Wireless adapters support WiFi Direct but the programming languages do not support it well?

P/S:

1. I have checked and my wireless adapter supports WiFi Direct.
2. I want to write a code to send a message through WiFi Direct from an Android device to a PC. (It is a project and I have to use Direct WiFi. Do not offer other approaches please.)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.devices.wifidirect.wifidirectdevice?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 0):

I think it is very similar question of [Java - Wifi API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869578/java-wifi-api)

Wireless network cards differ greatly among manufacturer and version.

If you would like to integrate with the wifi network cards with java, you could try JNI.